# Why python remove all rows here

Tags: python

I am trying to make a copy of a dataframe without duplicates.

```py
# Find duplicated bookingID values
duplicate_booking_ids = feature0[feature0.duplicated(subset='bookingID', keep=False)]['bookingID'].unique()

# Convert the array to Int64Index
duplicate_booking_ids_index = pd.Index(duplicate_booking_ids, name='bookingID')

# Print the Int64Index with name
print(duplicate_booking_ids_index)
```

gives

```
Index([1202590843006,  274877907034,  884763263056, 1073741824054,
       1056561954943, 1185410973787,  163208757379,  884763262976,
        841813590178,  300647710810,
       ...
         51539607558,  309237645374, 1022202216570,  764504178759,
       1597727834179,  395136991333,  257698037859,  541165879301,
        317827579962,  317827579936],
      dtype='int64', name='bookingID', length=20000)
```

I tried

```py
# Remove rows with specific bookingID values
duplicate_booking_ids = feature0[feature0.duplicated(subset='bookingID', keep=False)]['bookingID'].unique()

feature0_rm_dup = feature0[~feature0['bookingID'].isin(duplicate_booking_ids)]

# Print information before and after removing specific bookingID values
print('Before Removing Specific bookingID:', feature0.shape)
print('After Removing Specific bookingID:', feature0_rm_dup.shape)
print('Number of Rows Changed:', feature0.shape[0] - feature0_rm_dup.shape[0])
```

But i get

```
Before Removing Specific bookingID: (1613554, 12)
After Removing Specific bookingID: (0, 12)
Number of Rows Changed: 1613554
```

So why does all the rows get removed instead of just the original 2000?

Comment: Your requirement would be clearer if you gave a simplified example with data.